# how to exclude one specific ng-form in angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have the following form structure, how can I validate this form except for last item in `ng-repeat` ?  it is a kind of dynamic list of inputs and last input is an empty slot, and as the user types in the input, another empty input field is added to `items` collection and so on, how can I tell `parentForm` to ignore the last item?

```
<div ng-form="parentForm">

    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="itemForm">
         <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" required/> 
    </div>

    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="parentForm.$invalid" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use special `ngRepeat` property `$last` with combination with `ngRequired`:

```
<div ng-form="parentForm">

  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-form="itemForm">
     <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ng-required="!$last" /> 
  </div>

  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="parentForm.$invalid" />
</div>
```